# detecting iPhone app running on iPad in compatibility mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

My iPhone app is not universal but it has a feature that I'd like to enable for people playing on iPads.  Is there some way to detect that you're running on an iPad in compatibility mode?  The UIDevice methods for detecting machine specs all return the values you would get on an iPhone (on the simulator at least).  The only thing I can think of is detecting OS 3.2, but that technique won't work for long.

Comment: What do you mean by "compatability" mode? This is iOS, not Windows XP.

Comment: When you run a non-universal iPhone app on an iPad it runs in an emulated iPhone environment.  You'll have to excuse me for not knowing the exact term for it.

Comment: Yes. iPhone apps run on the iPad. In that case you already know you built an iPhone app, you just need to check if your running on the iPad, see my answer.

Comment: Might i also add that enabling iPad features in an iPhone app target seems silly. Why don't you do it properly and make the iPhone app a universal binary (iPad+iPhone) ?

Comment: Let's see, building a real universal app involves making the business decision to forgo separate iPhone/iPad versions, buying a $500 hardware device for testing, and completely reworking my UI with all the necessary QA that entails.  Enabling a feature involves getting the answer to one question and writing two or three lines of code.  Which one should I do before I submit my update tomorrow?

Comment: A couple of years after the fact, but Apple's own documentation calls this "compatibility mode". Check under the heading "Create Universal Apps" in this iAd doc: [Technical Note TN2264](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2264/_index.html) where it says: "iPhone apps running in compatibility mode on iPad..."

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Originally answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14864400/577237

Reposted since it's so short:

If the app is an iPhone app running in the emulator mode on an iPad, it will have a userInterfaceIdiom of Phone, but a model type of iPad. You can check this with the following code:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone &&
    [[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] hasPrefix:@"iPad"]) {
    // This app is an iPhone app running on an iPad
}
```

Comment: your code is incorrect. UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() will be equal to ipad for iPhone app running on iPad.

Comment: @RubberDuck I have to disagree with your assessment. I've created a test app in order to test this functionality: https://github.com/michaelpatzer/TestEmulationMode

Comment: this is strange because on your app the behavior is the expected but in two apps of mine, I see iPad as the idiom! WTF!!!!

Comment: I made the sample app as simple as possible to ensure no other variables are at play. If you message me directly, I'd be happy to take a look at the apps in question to try to debug the issue.

Comment: I've confirmed this code is still correct on iOS 8.

Comment: This is an old thread but I ran into the UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM thing for iOS12. For an iPhone only app running on the iPad Pro 3rd gen, UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() is returning UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone in case I request [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] front up, but get UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad in case is request  [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] later. I assume asking for the screens bounds is just a sample for calls triggering an evaluation of UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()?

Answer (score 9):

**1)** Use **UIDevice-Extension**  written by Erica Sadun. A very comprehensive class:
http://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension/blob/master/UIDevice-Hardware.m

**2)** Or you could also use the **UIDevice** class method:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] name]              // eg. "Brock's iPhone"
[[UIDevice currentDevice] model]             // eg. @"iPhone", @"iPod Touch"
[[UIDevice currentDevice] localizedModel]    // localized version of model
[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemName]        // eg. @"iPhone OS"
[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]     // eg. @"3.2"
[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]  // UDID, a unique string to identify the device
```

Each of the above lines will return an `NSString`. To which you can do a string comparison like so:

```
NSString *model = [[UIDevice currentDevice] model];
NSLog(@"Current device model: \"%@\"", model);
```

**3) Another way**:

http://www.drobnik.com/touch/2009/07/determining-the-hardware-model/
You will need to modify this to use the right hardware number for the iPad. Taken from the link above:

*UIDevice-hardware.h*

```
#import 

#define IPHONE_1G_NAMESTRING @"iPhone 1G"
#define IPHONE_3G_NAMESTRING @"iPhone 3G"
#define IPHONE_3GS_NAMESTRING @"iPhone 3GS"
#define IPOD_1G_NAMESTRING @"iPod touch 1G"
#define IPOD_2G_NAMESTRING @"iPod touch 2G"

@interface UIDevice (Hardware)
- (NSString *) platform;
- (NSString *) platformString;
@end
```

*UIDevice-hardware.m*

```
#import "UIDevice-hardware.h"
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

@implementation UIDevice (Hardware)

/*
 Platforms
 iPhone1,1 = iPhone 1G
 iPhone1,2 = iPhone 3G
 iPhone2,1 = iPhone 3GS
 iPod1,1   = iPod touch 1G
 iPod2,1   = iPod touch 2G
 */

- (NSString *) platform
{
 size_t size;
 sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &amp;size, NULL, 0);
 char *machine = malloc(size);
 sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &amp;size, NULL, 0);
 NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithCString:machine];
 free(machine);
 return platform;
}

- (NSString *) platformString
{
 NSString *platform = [self platform];
 if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"]) return IPHONE_1G_NAMESTRING;
 if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"]) return IPHONE_3G_NAMESTRING;
 if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"]) return IPHONE_3GS_NAMESTRING;
 if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])   return IPOD_1G_NAMESTRING;
 if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])   return IPOD_2G_NAMESTRING;
 return NULL;
}
@end
```

Comment: I don't have an iPad to test on, but in the iPad simulator `[[UIDevice currentDevice] model]` returns `iPhone Simulator`, not `iPad Simulator`.  I assume it will return `iPhone` instead of `iPad` when running on the device.  It's an emulated iPhone environment, so this is no surprise.

The `hw.machine` sysctl is an interesting suggestion, but on the iPad simulator it just returns `i386`.  Do you know what it returns on the iPad when running a non-universal iPhone app?

Comment: You shouldn't need to test this on the simulator. You need a real device, otherwise how are you to know wthat happens in the field environment?

Answer (score 3):

Did you check the "UIDevice.h" ? It has model property which u can find-out the iPhone,iPod,iPad devices

> NSString    *name;              //
>   e.g. "My iPhone"
>
> NSString    *model;             //
>   e.g. @"iPhone", @"iPod Touch"
>
> NSString    *localizedModel;    //
>   localized version of model
>
> NSString    *systemName;        //
>   e.g. @"iPhone OS"
>
> NSString    *systemVersion;     //
>   e.g. @"2.0"
>
> NSString    *uniqueIdentifier; **(DEPRECATED)**  // a
>   string unique to each device based on
>   various hardware info.

Comment: I don't have an iPad to test on, but in the iPad simulator `[[UIDevice currentDevice] model]` returns `iPhone Simulator`, not `iPad Simulator`.

Comment: I print [[UIDevice currentDevice] model] and it returned me "iPad"
:)

Comment: @n8gray: yes simulator is limited. only works on iOS devices.

Comment: Accepted for telling me what it does on the actual device.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to know whether you're running an iPhone app on an iPad, so you can scale the interface down to iPhone 4S size, it's worth noting that iPhone apps running on 12.9" iPad are presented at iPhone SE size. Adding a check for the main screen's scale will resolve this.

```
var isSmalliPhoneAppRunningOniPad: Bool {
    return UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone &&
           UIDevice.current.model.hasPrefix("iPad") && 
           UIScreen.main.scale == 2
}
```