# How to detect my iPhone app is being run on an iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, retina-display

I have an opengl application that renders better in RetinaDisplay mode (double scale factor) and I noticed the iPad emulates an iPhone app with a low resolution screen (normal scale factor).

I want to double the scale factor when my iPhone app is run on an iPad, in order to benefit from Retina Display graphics. But it seems the iPad really well fakes being an iPhone (which would be perfect if only it was a Retina Display one...)

When I force the double scale, it works very well (at least in simulator, I do not have an iPad to test).

So I need a way to know if I am run on an iPad despite many things telling me it to be an old iPhone.

Or maybe I should not try to do that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [detecting iPhone app running on iPad in compatibility mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242620/detecting-iphone-app-running-on-ipad-in-compatibility-mode)

Comment: Yes, looks pretty much like it, but no good answer found there.

Comment: Starting to think that it is a bug from Apple...

Answer (score -4, accepted):

you shouldn't be able to tell the difference, if its an iPhone app, then as far as it can tell it is running on an iPhone. if you want to target an iPad, then you need to build it for an iPad target.

Comment: an iPad can run any iphone app remember :P

Comment: apple have been very deliberate about this, the only way to ensure that apps would run out of the box, is if there was no way they could get returned something from the iPad, that they couldn't get from an iPhone.there are too many apps on the store that would be testing for hardware identifiers/screen res other edge cases, for apple to chance leaving it.

Comment: @Antwan any iPhone app can run on it, but it is in an emulated environment. if you want to do anything different on the iPad, it has to be built for the iPad... its because it needs to run any iPhone app that there is no way of detecting from an iPhone build that it is running on an iPad.

Comment: Fair enough. I still think it is not normal not to have RetinaDisplay graphics, but it is the problem of Apple and their iPhone simulator on the iPad, not mine then... Thank you.

Comment: are there any other apps made for iPhone that have retina display graphics on the iPad? the iPad came out before the iPhone was announced if i recall, and is a lower resolution screen(although higher than iPhone 3gs)

Comment: You actually can detect if the device is an iPad. See my answer below. It's from Apples guidelines on creating universal apps.

Comment: @shein, its not a universal application, its an iphone app. which is why the iPad apis aren't reporting that its an iPad. if its a universal application, then it is built against the iPad headers, so has the info available. http://www.mattcannon.co.uk/ipadexample.png shows how the iPhone app is being run.

Comment: @MCannon - what SDK version are you building for? (I want to replicate)

Comment: 4.2- to replicate you need to build an iPhone app, and then run it in the iPad simulator. if its a universal app your code runs as expected, and is the way i do it, but if its iPhone only, then it always returns  as an iPhone/iPod touch

Answer (score 21):

If the app is an iPhone app running in the emulator mode on an iPad, it will have a userInterfaceIdiom of Phone, but a model type of iPad. You can check this with the following code:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone &&
    [[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] hasPrefix:@"iPad"]) {
    // This app is an iPhone app running on an iPad
}
```

Comment: this will work only if the app is built as a universal

Comment: and peetonn, he is saying a NON-Universal iPhone only app running in the classic (1X / 2X) mode on ipads

Comment: I wonder why this one is not the accepted answer and the one which is not addressing the question is accepted one.

Answer (score 20):

If you are looking to make custom code (most likely custom UI related methods) for the iPad only then you can use (as Apple directs) the UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() method that exists in iOS 3.2 and later

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    // The device is an iPad running iPhone 3.2 or later.
}
else
{
    // The device is an iPhone or iPod touch.

}
```

You can read more here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html

This is the Apple recommended method

Comment: I think this is the best method, however, in this example, it says "3.2 or higher" which isnt the case for this method. This actually looks for the interface idiom, which is essentially the screen size of the device, not the iOS version.

For more info on the IDIOM, see: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/userInterfaceIdiom

Comment: Yes you're right it is only for iOS 3.2 and higher - but you can test if it exists and if it doesn't you know it's not iPad or iPhone 4G because they ship with iOS 3.2+ and if it does respond you can get both iOS version and the IDIOM

Comment: This is an answer for those who want to know if the applicaiton is run on iPad, but it works for universal apps run natively on the iPad. I wanted to know if my iPhone-only app was run on an iPad in order to switch on the Retina Display graphics, which is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Look up in the documentation, UIDevice:

For instance something like:
NSString *system = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemName];

Then by using [system isEqualToString:@"iPad"] whether its an ipad or not.

UIDevice is a very nice class, it also has stuff like multiTaskingSupported, systemVersion etc. gotta love UIKit ;)

Comment: I tried this solution, but it does not detect iPad. This is why I say it emulates very well the iPhone : it also pretends to be one for this function.

Answer (score 0):

i think it is that:

```
// Set hello to "Hello, <device or simulator>"!
```

## if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR

NSString *hello = @"Hello, iOS Simulator!";

## else

NSString *hello = @"Hello, iOS device!";

## endif

the link [apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/115-Configuring_Applications/configuring_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH19-SW13)

Comment: I'm afraid this is only valid because I am in iPad simulator, I am looking for something that will be true in the iPhone simulator of an iPad device, and I am pretty sure this flag does not correponds to that... But of course I cannot test.

Comment: That's actually a preprocessor makro. Won't have any effect once you've compiled the app, these kind of macros are striped out before the actual compilation takes place by the preprocessor.

Comment: This actually will only tell you if the app is being run in a simulated environment, or on an actual device, and has no influence on whether the platform is iPad or iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

about

> This actually will only tell you if
>   the app is being run in a simulated
>   environment, or on an actual device,
>   and has no influence on whether the
>   platform is iPad or iPhone.

In fact it says at compile time the target of the platform you are compiling for, thus before run you know and do the necessary for take care of something specific.

For example I have diferent URL for developing (running on simulator) and for production usage, so I do some like

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#define URL @"http://192.x.x.x/request"
#else
#define URL @"http://example.com/request"
#endif
```

Comment: Note that #define is a compiler directive meaning that value of URL will be determine at compile time, not at runtime.