# Detect iPhone specific application 'is running' on iPAD

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, emulation

I have an app which is developed for iPhone only. When user runs it on iPAD
it is not showing properly. I know how to detect "IS_iPAD" when project is universal but
when project is iPhone specific the USER DEVICE is always returned as iPhone.

How one can detect if iPhone specific application is run on iPAD?

Comment: If I understand right your question this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465832/how-to-detect-my-iphone-app-is-being-run-on-an-ipad/14864400#14864400

Comment: helped!!! it answered my question... Thanks

Answer (score 9):

For sake of completion here is the @MichaelPatzer answer pointed by @user42949

> If the app is an iPhone app running in the emulator mode on an iPad,
>   it will have a userInterfaceIdiom of Phone, but a model type of iPad.
>   You can check this with the following code:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone &&
    [[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] hasPrefix:@"iPad"]) {
    // This app is an iPhone app running on an iPad
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this different macro to know if you are using iPhone, iPhone 5 or iPad :

```
#define IS_IPHONE()     (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_IPAD()       (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_IPHONE5()    ((UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, if your code is layout-specific (which is how I got here):

```
CGSize screenSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
CGFloat screenRatio = MIN(screenSize.width / screenSize.height, screenSize.height / screenSize.width); // account for rotation
if(screenRatio > 6.65 && screenRatio < 6.67) {
    // iPad is 6.66666
}
```